# Phaser sprites not colliding when standing still

Tags: collision-detection, collision, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I am making a simple Mario like platformer and I want kill the enemies when the player character jumps at their head, and kill the player when he collides with the enemies from the side.

I have managed to do it when the player sprite is moving, however, if the player stands still the enemies just pass through him without killing him.

You can see all the code in GitHub repo here:

https://github.com/failedCoder/failedCoder.github.io

And you can try a game here(takes a few secs to load):

https://failedcoder.github.io/

Comment: Do you use the 'collide' method in the 'update' function? In addition you have activated physics in the sprites and in the game?

Comment: I use the collide method in update function,but I havent activated physics for enemies.After activating it when I stand still enemy sprites no longer pass through the player,but instead they die when colliding with player sprite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First enable physics for the player and enemies, set velocity, now it's your choice how to move enemies right and left, I will give you an example how to move them left. So, the important thing to remember is this: "Physics system only works if at least one body has velocity".

```
enemies = game.add.group();
enemies.enableBody = true;

var enemy1 = enemies.create(230,490,'invader');
//enemy1.body.gravity.y = 300;  
enemy1.body.velocity.x = -100;  

 var enemy2 = enemies.create(430,490,'invader');
//enemy2.body.gravity.y = 300;
enemy2.body.velocity.x = -100;
```

In update function add this code:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(player, enemies, touchingEnemies);
```

Then create a function touchingEnemies:

```
function touchingEnemies(player, enemy)
{
    if (player.body.touching.right || player.body.touching.left)
    {
        // player is dead
        player.alpha = .5;
    }
    else if (player.body.touching.down)
    {
        // player is jumping on enemy, kill it
        enemy.alpha = .5;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had player.body.touching.bottom instead of .down,now the enemies get destroyed when I'm standing still,instead of just passing through the player character like they did before,they still kill the player character if it moves.Here is my code `function enemiesInteraction(player,enemies){

    crush.play();

    if(player.body.touching.left || player.body.touching.right){

        player.kill();

    }
    else if(player.body.touching.down){

        score += 200;

        scoreText.text = 'Score: ' + score;

        enemies.kill();

    }

}`

Comment: Can you kill the enemy if you jump on it? If enemies touching you from the right or left side they will kill you of course, I don't understand what it the problem exactly? This code works I use it in my games. I have edited answer, please add that code to upadate and see player's and enemy's physics bodies. Maybe this will show you the problem, then please update the game I will check it.

Comment: I can kill the enemy if I jump on it,the problem is that the enemy kill the player character if they hit him from the side only if the player character is moving,if player character stands still enemies die,instead of the player characher.For some reason when player sprite stands still this part of code is executed ` else if (player.body.touching.down)
    {
        // player is jumping on enemy, kill it
    }`,instead of ` if (player.body.touching.right || player.body.touching.left)
    {
        // player is dead
    }`

Comment: Long story short,if PC runs into a enemy sprite-PC dies,if PC jumps on the enemy head-enemy dies,the problem is that when PC stands still-the enemy dies when they collide instead of PC.

Comment: I will try adding the game.debug.body to the update function to see if that helps.

Comment: Then, I know what is your problem, physics (collide, overlap) will only works if one or two objects have velocity. It means you should move enemies by setting their velocity like: enemy.body.velocity.x = -100; Currently you move enemies using tween. I will update the answer again.